# ORACLE PL SQL PROCEDURE WITH MULTIPLE IF

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

Is it correct to declare multiple `IF`s on PL SQL like the code below. I JUST GOT THIS ERROR --

> PACKAGE BODY HAS PROBLEMS ...could not find program unit being called

```
PROCEDURE CONSULTA_EVALCT(VAR_R VARCHAR2,VAR_A VARCHAR2, IO_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR) 
IS         
V_CURSOR T_CURSOR; 
BEGIN
IF(VAR_R='0' AND VAR_A='0')THEN 
    OPEN V_CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT *from table1; 
    IO_CURSOR := V_CURSOR; 
END IF; 
IF(VAR_R='0' AND VAR_A<>0) THEN 
    OPEN V_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *FROM table2; 
    IO_CURSOR := V_CURSOR; 
END IF; 
IF(VAR_R<>'0' AND VAR_A<>0) THEN
    OPEN V_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *FROM table3; 
    IO_CURSOR := V_CURSOR; 
END IF; 
END CONSULTA_EVALCT;
```

Comment: Yes, you can have as many conditional statements as you like.  That has nothing to do with your error.  Please show the COMPLETE error message,stack trace.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. you are right, if is not the problem. I have solved , have a nice weekend

Comment: Alter package <package_name> compile it will solve the problem;

Answer (score 0):

First, are you adding your procedure to the Package head?, and the right way to your conditions "if you want only to use IF" is the following:

```
IF(VAR_R='0') THEN
   IF (A= '0')
      OPEN V_CURSOR FOR SELECT *from table1; 
      --..
     ELSE 
       OPEN V_CURSOR FOR SELECT *FROM table2; 
       --..
   END IF;
ELSE IF (VAR_A<>0) THEN
       OPEN V_CURSOR FOR SELECT *FROM table3; 
       --..
END IF;
--..
```

I suggest instead of multiple if in that case to use CASE instead